# Render html element to view of component

Tags: modal-dialog, dart, bootstrap-modal, angular2-services, angular-dart

I have a modal `service` in which a modal widnow HTML is got from an URL and appended to the DOM body. is it possible the modal element inside of the service to be attached (rendered) to a view of `component`?

problem in this case : angular bindings for variables and functions in component dont work in modal element appended to DOM.

## service:

```
@Injectable()
class ModalService {
  String templateUrl;
  final BrowserClient _client = new BrowserClient();

  ModalService();

  Future getTemplate(String url, {Map<String, String> headers}) async {
    return await _client.get(url);
  }

  Future getModal(String url) async {
    var response = await getTemplate(url);
    var modalTemplate = response.body;

    if (modalTemplate == null) return null;

    Element modalElement =
        new Element.html(modalTemplate, validator: new NeutralNodeValidator());

    document.body.children.add(modalElement);

    return modalElement;
  }
}
```

## component:

```
class UsersManagingComponent(this._userManagingService, this._routeParams,
      this._location, this._authHttp, this._modalService, this.ref, this._viewContainer);

  /// Open Modal
  Future edit() async {
    await _modalService.getModal('templates/users/modals/editUser.html');
    context.callMethod(r'$', ['.modal']).callMethod('modal', ['show']);
  }

}
```

Comment: What part exactly causes troubles?

Comment: binding in modal template does not work with component variables

Comment: What binding? You mean some Angular bindings in `editUser.html`? Angular bindings **only** work when added statically to a components template, otherwise they just don't and there is no way you can make it work. In Dart this has to be in a components template when `pub build` is run, in TS it would be possible to load the component compiler at runtime and compile a component on demand. Dart doesn't support that and doesn't plan to.

Comment: yup. i mean bindings in `editUser.html`. thank you

Comment: You can do it in a non-Angular way, using `querySelector('x').text = 'foo'` or `querySelector('y').onClick.listen(onClick)`, ...

Comment: I think it is an ugly way for doing.  thanks @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: I don't know what kind of modal you're using. If the template is static, you can dynamically create a component instance and pass that component instance instead of the HTML if your modal supports that. The component then can use Angular bindings and other Angular stuff.

Comment: unfortunately I have a lot of various modals with differnet forms and buttons. I perefer to load templates instead of making various components

Comment: I'd say that's the ugly part. You shouldn't avoid creating components in Angular. They are the basic building blocks and it doesn't need much in addition to a template to get a component.